# How to create UNDO button, flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my project I have a delete button that deletes some data from firebase firestore, what i'm trying to do is showing a snackbar with **undo** word, when it's pressed the process will be cancelled and no data will be deleted. I haven't found a solution yet. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Timer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.0/dart-async/Timer-class.html) to create a callback that can be canceled anytime before the timer runs out.

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  
  final cancelable = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      // The delete function should be here
      print('canceled after 3 seconds');
    });
    
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), cancelable.cancel);
  
}
```

In this example the `print()` callback gets canceled after three seconds, but you could pass the `cancelable.cancel()` function as a callback for the undo button and cancel the deletion on **Firestore** by clicking it before the `Timer` runs out

Answer (score 0):

Deletes in Firestore are permanent; once you delete a document it is gone.

If you want to give the option to undo the deletion, you'll want to:

- Either create the document in another collection before deleting it from the main one. For example, a common implementation is to have a subcollection with deleted documents, or even the entire history of each document.
- Or you mark the documents as deleted, instead of really deleting them. This type of marking is typically referred to as a tombstone.

Comment: That is, when the data is deleted, it will be placed in another collection, and if I click restore, the data will be written back to the displayed collection, right? But if there are many such moments, the second collection will be clogged and not cleared, will this not affect the performance of the database itself?

Comment: Read performance on Firestore depends on how much data you read, not on the size of the collection. So "collection being clogged" is not a thing on Firestore. --- If you want to regularly clear up older backups that is an option too of course. --- Also: if this answer was useful to you, don't forget to his the upvote button next to it. :)

Comment: Can I transfer or copy a document from one collection to another Firestore ?

Comment: If I delete a document in the main collection, I need to move it to another collection for deleted files and then, if necessary, I can restore it (move it back)